# What does Misplaced \cr in latex error mean

Tags: errors

What does it mean

```
! Misplaced \cr.
\math@cr@@@ ->\cr 
In latex error.
```

in this document

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,color}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \begin{document}
     \begin{align*}
     \begin{pmatrix }
    \int_0^1 f(s) ds  \\
    int_0^\om g(s) ds 
     \end{pmatrix}
     \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

Your example generates

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment pmatrix   undefined.
```

because of the spurious space in `\begin{pmatrix }` and

```
! Undefined control sequence.
```

because `\om` is not defined.

It does only generates the error in the subject line if you ignore those errors and let TeX recover. Subsequent errors are nearly always spurious.

In this case `\cr` is the TeX primitive for a new line in an aligment which is used in the definition of `\\`. because the inner `pmatrix` did not start because of the first error, TeX takes the `\\` as ending the outer alignment row inside the group, which is an error.