# ifmtarg in tabular does not work

Tags: macros, conditionals

I tried to create my custom class for lab reports, which needs to have a tabular on the titlepage which contains the dates on that I gave the report to my assistant for correction. In order to make things for the user as easy as possible I wanted to appear the dates and text automatically when they are defined by a command like `\firsthandin{2017-01-06}`. As I need to define `\firsthandin`, my thought was that it is useless to check whether this macro is defined, it is of course; but rather whether the argument is empty or differs from the default value. So I tried using `\ifmtarg` from `ifmtarg.sty`. Here is what I have so far:

### protokoll.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{protokoll}[2017/01/05 v1.0]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside]{scrartcl}
%=====================================================
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
%=====================================================
\newcommand{\@firsthandin}{}
\newcommand{\firsthandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\@firsthandin}{#1}}

\newcommand{\@secondhandin}{Unknown}
\newcommand{\secondhandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\@secondhandin}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\ifmtarg{\@firsthandin}{}{First date} & \ifmtarg{\@firsthandin{}{\@firsthandin} \\
Second date & \@secondhandin \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{titlepage}
}
```

The second line is just to check whether there is another mistake regarding the variables.
I also tried changing the first line of the tabular to `\ifmtarg{\@firsthandin}{}{First date & \@firsthandin \\}` but this produces the same errors.

### mwe_protokoll.tex

```
\documentclass{protokoll}
\firsthandin{05.01.2017}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I get errors about `Misplaced \cr` which is according to @DavidCarlisle ([What does Misplaced \cr in latex error mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91559/what-does-misplaced-cr-in-latex-error-mean)) used in the definition of `\\`, so I guess `\ifmtarg` messes up with the linebreaks of the tabular. Any ideas how to solve this?
(It is not important whether an empty space or "really nothing" is given out)

Comment: The command is `\@ifmtarg`, but there is another issue with `\noalign`, I suppose

Comment: why not use `etoolbox` its macro examination macros are much more power full. Plus it is meant to he used in user space (aka no @ in macro names)

Comment: @daleif: The `\@ifmtarg` is not in user space here, it's class code (but I agree with you about the possibly easier `etoolbox` approach)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes the missing `@` was actually the problem...quite easy and a quite stupid mistake from me. But thanks for your eagle eyes. I will accept your answer as you solved my problem but I think I will use the `etoolbox` method because it is even easier.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you're right, but it seems I do not need the `\edef` part in the version I posted.

Comment: @daleif: True. I did not check the definition of `\ifdefvoid` but it seems to expand internally. (And I did not mean to steal the tick!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't collect points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditionals in tabular cells are tricky. They should be expanded first using something like `\edef\x{\if...}\x`

I did not change the driver file `protokoll.tex`, so please load from the O.P.

```
\ProvidesClass{protokoll}[2017/01/05 v1.0]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside]{scrartcl}
%=====================================================
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
%=====================================================
\newcommand{\@firsthandin}{}
\newcommand{\firsthandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\@firsthandin}{#1}}

\newcommand{\@secondhandin}{Unknown}
\newcommand{\secondhandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\@secondhandin}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \edef\x{\@ifmtarg{\@firsthandin}{}{First Date}}\x & \edef\x{\@ifmtarg{\@firsthandin}{}{\@firsthandin}}\x \\
  Second date & \@secondhandin \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{titlepage}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using `etoolbox`, I've also renamed the holder macros so they can be used in user space for this example.

Note that `etoolbox` contains a `\ifblank` macro, but that cannot be used to test the emptiness of a given macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\firsthandinXX}{}
\newcommand{\firsthandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\firsthandinXX}{#1}}

\newcommand{\secondhandinXX}{Unknown}
\newcommand{\secondhandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\secondhandinXX}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\ifdefvoid{\firsthandinXX}{}{First date} & \ifdefvoid{\firsthandinXX}{}{\firsthandinXX} \\
Second date & \secondhandinXX \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{titlepage}
}


\firsthandin{05.01.2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors in your code: check the differences.

### `protokoll.cls`

```
\ProvidesClass{protokoll}[2017/01/05 v1.0]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside]{scrartcl}
%=====================================================
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
%=====================================================
\newcommand*{\@firsthandin}{}
\newcommand{\firsthandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\@firsthandin}{#1}}

\newcommand{\@secondhandin}{Unknown}
\newcommand{\secondhandin}[1]{\renewcommand{\@secondhandin}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \expandafter\@ifnotmtarg\expandafter{\@firsthandin}{First date & \@firsthandin \\}%
  Second date & \@secondhandin \\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{titlepage}%
}
```

No need for a `table` environment, first of all; then the correct command is `\@ifmtarg`, but `\@ifnotmtarg` is easier here; you were missing a brace, too.

You need to expand `\@firsthandin` in order to see whether it is empty or not.

### `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside]{protokoll}

\firsthandin{05.01.2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Oh  you are right, `\@ifnotmtarg` is in fact easier. Thanks for your improvements.