# How do I align a simple list on the left?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I have this sample (reduced from the document I started with):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
And then the first several terms of $v$ are
\begin{align*}
v_0, \\
{\lambda v_0 + B}, \\
{\lambda^2 v_0 + 2 \lambda B + \lambda A}, \\
{\lambda^3 v_0 + 3 \lambda^2 B + 3 \lambda^2 A}, \\
{\lambda^4 v_0 + 4 \lambda^3 B + 6 \lambda^3 A}, \\
{\lambda^5 v_0 + 5 \lambda^4 B + 10 \lambda^4 A}, \\
\ldots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This runs through LaTeX without error, but does the wrong thing; it aligns all the commas instead of aligning to the left. I don't want that. I want these terms lined up so that they have a common left edge.

When I try to say "align to the left" by replacing the fourth line with `\begin[l]{align*}`, I get an error that I don't know how to interpret:

```
! Misplaced \cr.
\math@cr@@@ ->\cr 

l.12 \end{align*}
```

The question on this site [What does Misplaced \cr in latex error mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91559/what-does-misplaced-cr-in-latex-error-mean) seems like it ought to help, but I can't interpret what the answer means for my example.

Comment: You put no `&`, so all your lines are considered to be on the *left* side of the alignment (hence *right*-aligned), and there's an implicit `&` at the end of each line. Simply put one at the *beginning* of each line.

Comment: But why do I get an error once I add an `[l]` and not without it?

Comment: Where do you put `[l]`? As an optional argument of `align`?

Comment: I think so? As I said in my question, I replace `\begin{align*}` with `\begin[l]{align*}`.

Comment: It can't work. There's no such syntax. The alignment points are marked with `&`. See my other comment under berkus'answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you encase most of the rows in pairs of curly braces?

Comment: Because I initially had a few rows of terms separated by commas, each term inside `$`s, the whole paragraph inside a `{quote}` env, and there I didn't want terms split by line breaks. When I changed my mind to one term per row, I didn't undo the extra braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may place your equations in an `array` environment with left alignment:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
    \begin{document}
    And then the first several terms of $v$ are
    \[
      \begin{array}{l}
                  v_0, \\
        \lambda   v_0 + B, \\
        \lambda^2 v_0 + 2 \lambda   B +    \lambda   A, \\
        \lambda^3 v_0 + 3 \lambda^2 B + 3  \lambda^2 A, \\
        \lambda^4 v_0 + 4 \lambda^3 B + 6  \lambda^3 A, \\
        \lambda^5 v_0 + 5 \lambda^4 B + 10 \lambda^4 A, \\
      \end{array}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

**Edit No 1:**

Or you can use an `align*` environment, with alignment markers at the beginning of each line:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
    \begin{document}
    And then the first several terms of $v$ are
    \begin{align*}
      &          v_0, \\
      &\lambda   v_0 + B, \\
      &\lambda^2 v_0 + 2 \lambda   B +    \lambda   A, \\
      &\lambda^3 v_0 + 3 \lambda^2 B + 3  \lambda^2 A, \\
      &\lambda^4 v_0 + 4 \lambda^3 B + 6  \lambda^3 A, \\
      &\lambda^5 v_0 + 5 \lambda^4 B + 10 \lambda^4 A, \\
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit No 2:**

The equations are aligned at `&`. To demonstrate:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
And then the first several terms of $v$ are
  \begin{align*}
    &v_0,                                             & \textrm{Aligns here}\\
    &{\lambda v_0 + B},                               & \textrm{Aligns here}\\
    &{\lambda^2 v_0 + 2 \lambda B + \lambda A},       & \text{Aligns}\\
    &{\lambda^3 v_0 + 3 \lambda^2 B + 3 \lambda^2 A}, & \text{Aligns here long}\\
    &{\lambda^4 v_0 + 4 \lambda^3 B + 6 \lambda^3 A}, & \text{Ali}\\
    &{\lambda^5 v_0 + 5 \lambda^4 B + 10 \lambda^4 A},& \text{Aligns here very long}
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit No 3:**

`&` here has two purposes: setup the columns and setup the point where the equations will all be aligned. To demonstrate it, we should use equations with `=` sign, which are actually `align` is mainly used for. (see [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath)) :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
And then the first several terms of $v$ are
  \begin{align*}
          x&=y     &    w&=z              &  a&=b+c\\
         2x&=-y    &   3w&=\frac{1}{2}z   &  a&=b\\
    -4 + 5x&=2+y   &  w+2&=-1+w           & ab&=cb
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

1st, 3rd and 5th `&` determines the location of `=`, and the others determine the number of columns. This is how `align` environment is setup.

[image]

Comment: Why would this be needed? Why can't I just put `[l]` on the `align*`?

Comment: *align** has no optional argument. `aligned` has, but it is for the vertical placement (`[t]`or `[b]`).

Comment: Experts please correct me if I am wrong: `align*` works like/as a LaTeX table. `&` defines the columns and `\\\` defines new row.

Comment: Then, and this may be a stupid question, why does adding an optional argument not either do nothing or give an error even vaguely related to the optional argument? In fact, it seems that `align*` does have an optional argument, but it means "throw an uninformative error at the end of the environment".

Comment: @DanielMartin It has not, any `[]` argument should output brackets in your document. But only if you use the typical environment optional argument syntax `\begin{align*}[]`. Any other syntax is not accepted either (`\begin[]{align*}` throws an error, because `\begin` does not have optional arguments).

Comment: That's not though what I see. What I see is an error on the `\end{align*}` line talking about `\cr`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to get rid of the many (pointless) pairs of curly braces. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Probably `&& \text{...}` rather than `&\textrm{...}` is better.

Comment: Not ‘probably’ – surely: with only one `&`, the text is right-aligned, but it can't be detected here, as it's always the same sentence.

Comment: To demonstrate what @Bernard pointed, I modified the answer.