# How to tell LaTeX to stop at the first error?

Tags: errors

Similarly to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91559/20929), 
I get a `misplaced \cr` error, which is probably a symptom of a previous error. However, my file is very large and I do not see where the previous error is.

Can I tell LaTeX to not try to recover from errors on its own, but just stop at the first error it encounters?

I tried the flag `-halt-on-error` but it just stops at the `misplaced \cr` error, which is not very helpful.

EDIT: I compile with `latex` from the command line.

Comment: Well then you probably really have a misplaced \cr. E.g.  a `&` when you should have a \\.

Comment: I would look at the log file after the compilation is finished, and see where the first error is. You can get up from your chair while the compilation is going on, so longer compilation time is a bonus: https://xkcd.com/303/